# AWS App Runner region environment variable

Tags: amazon-app-runner

I want to build a .net 7 web app and do a source code repository deployment to aws app runner.  I will add one instance in us-east-1 and another in eu-west-1.  How do I access the region name that the code is being run on from the .net code?  Does app runner have some environment variable with that?

Comment: If all that what you want to do is to have access to the region the code is running on, you can create an environment variable yourself for that and set the region. If you are using Cloudformation, Terraform or any other IaC tool, it should be fairly easy.